# Tabhost abrir uma nova acitivity apos clicar em uma lista

Tags: java, android

Galera, sou iniciante em android minha duvida e a seguinte.
Conheci o componente TabHost e achei muito interessante implementa-lo no aplicativo.
O aplicativo tem uma lista com os restaurantes e a pessoa escolhe o restaurante ele abre uma outra acitivity com os cardapios de acordo com o restaurante escolhido, está funcionando porém quando eu escolho o restaurante ele abre uma nova activity e o Tabhost desaparece.
Minha dúvida e a seguinte como abrir essa nova Activity dentro do tabhost(tabspec)? Segue o código:

Criação das tabs:

```
public class tabs extends TabActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedido);

        // create the TabHost that will contain the Tabs
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup();

        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Aba 1");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this, lista_restaurantes.class));
        tab1.setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_restaurante));

        TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Aba 2");
        tab2.setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_promo));
        tab2.setContent(new Intent(this, promocoes.class));

        TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Aba 3");
        tab3.setIndicator("",
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_carrrinho));
        tab3.setContent(new Intent(this, carrinho.class));

        /** Add the tabs to the TabHost to display. */
        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Ele carrega a classe `lista_restaurante` dentro do `TabSpec`

```
public class lista_restaurantes extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lista_restaurantes);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    restauranteList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   // chama restaurante
   new restaurante().execute()
    // Cria lista com Vendas no Dia
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Quando Selecionar um restaurante
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // OBTEM o valor da ID
            String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid)).getText()
                    .toString();

             Chama intent com o cardapio de acordo com restaurante
             Intent intent = new
            Intent(lista_restaurantes.this,lista_caradapio.class);

             intent.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

             Chama a acctivity lista_cardapio
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Como chamar a `lista_cardapio.class` dentro do tabspec?

Comment: Achei este link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213057/android-tabs-open-new-activity-with-every-tab-using-layout-include vou testar!!

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma pesquisada, achei a seguinte função:

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent) {
        View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,
                newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP))
                .getDecorView();
        this.setContentView(view);
}
```

Resolveu o meu problema. Pode fechar o tópico.